# Is my proof true? (problem about operator theory and measure theory)

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory, operator-theory, lp-spaces

The following is the problem which I wrote a solution. Please look at a glance and leave your comments. Please let me know if there is a flaw in my solution or please make a hint for another solution.

> **Problem:**
>   Let 
>   $\mathbb{A}$
>   be a measurable subset of 
>   $\mathbb{R}$. 
>   For every 
>   $f \in L^{1}(\mathbb{R})$ 
>   and for every 
>   $ y \in \mathbb{R}.$ 
>   Let
>   $$T(f,y)=\int_{\mathbb{A}}f(x-y)dx $$
>   (a) Prove that for every 
>   $y\in \mathbb{R},$
>   the function
>   $f\mapsto T(f,y)$
>   is continuous on
>   $ L^{1}(\mathbb{R}). $
>
> (b) Prove that for every 
>   $ f\in L^{1}(\mathbb{R}) $ 
>   the function 
>   $y\mapsto T(f,y)$
>   is continuous on
>   $\mathbb{R}.$

Here is what I have done:

> (a) Let 
>   $f_{n}\to f  $
>   on 
>   $ L^{1}(\mathbb{R}). $
>   Then
>   $$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\int_{\mathbb{R}}\vert f_{n}- f \vert dx=0 $$
>   Now, 
>   $$\int_{\mathbb{R}}\vert T(f_{n},y)-T(f,y) \vert dy= \int_{\mathbb{R}}\vert \int _{\mathbb{A}}( f_{n}(x-y)-f(x-y))dx\vert dy $$
>   $$\leq \int_{\mathbb{A}}( \int _{\mathbb{R}}\vert f_{n}(x-y)-f(x-y)\vert dy) dx\to 0 $$
>   (b)Let 
>   $y_{n}\to y,$ we have that
>   $$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\vert T(f,y_{n})-T(f,y) \vert= \lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\vert \int_{\mathbb{A}}(f(x-y_{n})-f(x-y)) dx\vert$$
>   Since 
>   $f\in L^{1}(\mathbb{R})$
>   so there exist
>   $s_{m}\in C_{c}(\mathbb{R})$ 
>   such that
>   $s_{m}\to f.$
>   Therefore, 
>   $$ \lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \int_{\mathbb{A}}(f(x-y_{n})-f(x-y))dx=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\int_{\mathbb{A}}\lim\limits_{m\to\infty}(s_{m}(x-y_{n})-s_{m}(x-y))dx $$
>   $$=\lim\limits_{m\to\infty}\int_{\mathbb{A}}\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}(s_{m}(x-y_{n})-s_{m}(x-y))dx=0 $$

Comment: How would you prove $\int_{\mathbb{A}}(\int_{\mathbb{R}}|f_n(x-y)-f(x-y)|dy)dx \to 0$ ? As I see, $\int_{\mathbb{R}}|f_n(x-y)-f(x-y)|dy$ is a constant number to x, but what if $m(A)$ is not finite?

Comment: You should prove $|T(f_n,y)-T(f,y)|\to 0$ instead of $\int_{\mathbb{A}}|T(f_n,y)-T(f,y)|dy$.

Comment: @XIAODAQU How do you check if $g_n\rightarrow 0$ in $L^1$? Is it different than checking if $\int |g_n-0|\rightarrow 0$?

Comment: @AmirHoseinSadeghiManesh: I know what you mean. But actually, when we say $T$ is continuous on $L^1$, we refer to its definition domain. Note that $T(f,y)$ is a real number, and I don't think the problem wants a real number's integration.

Comment: @XIAODAQU $T(f,y)$ is a number but $T(-,y)$ is a function.

Comment: @AmirHoseinSadeghiManesh: Then how would you define the integral of a function whose independent variable is a function? You see, y is fixed in this problem, so you can't consider $\int T(f,y)dy$. And $\int T(f,y)df$ just doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible proof for 2.

$\forall\varepsilon>0$

1. $\exists\ \delta>0\ s.t. \forall F\subset\mathbb{R} \ \&\ m(F)<\delta$, $\int_F|f(x-y_n)-f(x-y)|dx<\varepsilon/4$ for all $n$.
2. $\exists N$ enough large such that $\int_{\mathbb{R}\backslash[-N, N]}|f(x-y_n)-f(x-y)|dx<\varepsilon/4$ for all $n$.
3. $\exists$ close set $E\subset\mathbb{R}$ such that $m(\mathbb{R}-E)<\delta$ and $f$ is continuous on $E$.

We can easily get these conclusions by a simple inequality $\int_S|f(x-y_n)-f(x-y)|dx\leq\int_S|f(x-y_n)|dx+\int_S|f(x-y)|dx$, where $S$ is any measurable set.

let $x_n=y_n-y\to0$, and we have

\begin{align}
&|\int_Af(x-y_n)-f(x-y)dx|\\
& \leq\int_\mathbb{R}|f(x-y_n)-f(x-y)|dx\\
& \leq\varepsilon/4+\int_{[-N, N]}|f(x-y_n)-f(x-y)|dx\\
& =\varepsilon/4+\int_{[-N-y, N-y]}|f(x-x_n)-f(x)|dx
\end{align}

Let $G\triangleq E\cap(E+x_n)\cap[-N-y, N-y]$

So $ [-N-y, N-y]\subset G+[\mathbb{R}-E]+[\mathbb{R}-(E+x_n)]$

Due to conclusion 3

original formula $\leq3\varepsilon/4+\int_G|f(x-x_n)-f(x)|dx$

f is uniform continuous on G. So when $|x_n|$ is small enough

original formula $\leq\varepsilon$

Answer (score 2):

Your proof for 1 is incorrect: You do not know if $T(f,y)$ is in $L^1(\Bbb R)$ so $\int_{Bbb R} |T(f,y)-T(f_n,y)|\,dy$ does not make sense. For example if $f=\chi_{[0,1]}$ and $\Bbb A= \Bbb R$ you have $T(f,y)=1$ which is certainly not integrable.

To correct it:
\begin{align}
|T(f,y)-T(f_n,y)|&=\left|\int_{\Bbb A}f(x-y)-f_n(x-y)\,dx\right|≤\int_{\Bbb A}|f(x-y)-f_n(x-y)|\,dx\\
&≤\int_{\Bbb R}|f(x-y)-f_n(x-y)|\,dx=\|f-f_n\|_{L^1}
\end{align}
This converges to zero so $T$ is continuous in $f$ for fixed $y$.

Your proof for 2 is also incorrect: It is unclear exactly what you want to do but it looks like you want to pull the limit in $n$ past the integral and swap it with the limit in $m$ in the following expression:
$$\lim_n \int_{\Bbb A} \lim_m f(x-y)- s_m(x-y_n)\,dx$$
You cannot do this without comment. I'm not sure about a correct proof at the moment.